# existence theorem of eliptic equation

Tags: analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Consider $\Omega \subset R^n$ a bounded and open set with $\partial \Omega$ smooth . Consider the problem:
$$ - \Delta u  +  au = f   \text{ in } \Omega $$
 $$ u = 0    \text{ in } \partial \Omega $$

where $a \geq 0$ is a constant.

If $f \in C^1 (\Omega) \cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ , then exist a solution $u$ for the problem with $u \in C^{2}(\Omega) \cap C(\overline{\Omega})$?

If the answer is yes, please say to me a basic reference to find this result. thanks in advance !

Comment: Try to work out Remark 25, page 306 of Brezis book: http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~karch/analiza_nieliniowa/ref/BREZIS__Functional_Analysis__Sobolev_Spaces_and_Partial_Differential_Equations__Universitext_.pdf